# Facebook App Review iOS - cannot select "Download it from the Apple App Store"

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to get my app reviewed on Facebook. Simulator build isn't working and my only option is to let the people at Facebook download my app through the App Store.

The App Store app is only available in the Netherlands (the facebook app is not country restricted), but I have (temporarily, until the App Review is finished) made it available in the U.S.
I can access the app through https://itunes.apple.com/us/ so I know for a fact that my app is now available in the U.S. App Store

However, in the Facebook App Review process, the button "Download it from the Apple App Store" is still greyed out. Is there anything more I need to do?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: _“I can access the app through https://itunes.apple.com/us/ so I know for a fact that the app is now available in the U.S”_ - that means your “Apple” app is now available in the US. That has little to do with whatever restrictions you might have configured for your Facebook app.

Comment: Ah, sorry. "app" in this context does indeed refer to the Apple app. My facebook app itself is not country restricted. I'll change the description!

Comment: Not sure how frequently Facebook re-checks those settings with the app store.

Comment: Yup, I also think this is just a matter of Facebook not updating the status of the app. Can't be sure though. Too bad it doesn't check when restarting the App Review.

Comment: Try changing/removing and re-adding the App Store ID in the (Facebook) App settings - it should cause Facebook to re-scrape iTunes looking for your updated app details

Answer (score 1):

The button became clickable the day after.
It's not completely clear why, but Facebook probably checks the availability settings of the app every day or so, instead of upon opening the App Review dialog (as I originally thought).